# remove characters from the table in oracle and update accordingly

Tags: oracle

I have one field in the table which contain alphanumeric string, now i want to remove the characters from that particular field and udpate the table accordinigly.

For Example

```
NAME
-----
SUMIT
123SU
123SUW234
```

After updation by the SQL table should be look like below

```
NAME
-----

123
123234
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table set name = regexp_replace(name,'[^[:digit:]]',null)
where  regexp_like (name,'[^[:digit:]]');
```